# How much Latency is caused by one Router?

Tags: networking, ping

I don't know if this question is good to be posted on this site. If not, I'm sorry. I coulnd't find any answer to it though...

Are there any results available stating how much latency is, in average, introduced by a router?
So for example in Lan: PC1 -> Router -> PC2. 
Or over the net: PC1 -> Router1 ...... -> Server.

For example, in my LAN: I'm pinging my Desktop from Smartphone. It takes about 6ms each. So, can i say that every router needs about 6ms (substracted the time the network cards need)? Because the distance is... well, 5 meters.

Would the ping time be less if i would do it over an ad hoc network?

Every information is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to consider that ping uses ICMP, which is a low priority protocol, and devices tend to save it for last when processing. Ping is not really a good test for determining latency, and what it give you often is completely different than the latency experienced by other protocols.

Comment: Good addition, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It mostly depends on both hardware.

Ping your router, then ping another computer on the network, that will tell you an average on how much it **COULD** take.

The specific depends on the circumstances.
I'm on WiFi pinging one of my servers on the LAN and I get 1ms to the server and 1ms to the router.

That will greatly differ if the router is low end or has to route a lot of traffic (QOS).

So, you need to consider:

- How much time will take the router to find the appropriate route.
- How much time will take to the interface to execute that route.
- How much time will take to the other end to respond to that petition.

Comment: Thanks! One more question and I'll accept. In the scenario you've described: "I'm on WiFi pinging one of my servers on the LAN and I get 1ms to the server and 1ms to the router." So in this case using an ad hoc network wouldn't improve the latency because the router doesn't have a noticeable impact, right?

Comment: In my case, the router has a way too low impact to be improved by using a  "direct" connection with an ad hoc network. Also, you need to consider that an adhoc network just "moves" the router from a physical device into one of the end devices, so the whole "routing time" is still there, just on a (hopefully) more powerfull device.